# Is there any hope to update antiquated display drivers?

Tags: drivers, resolution, gpu

I just inherited a Poweredge R710 server with a Matrox G200 GPU. The OS I have on the server is Windows 2012 R2. The resolution on the screen is driving me crazy. Is there any way I could update this driver or fix this problem? Or I'm I stuck with this poor resolution forever?

Comment: Not neccessarily a solution to your problem but, have you considered doing your work on it using remote desktop? That would allow you to use the resolution of the computer connecting to it.

Comment: You have PCI-e expansion slots, so you could install a better graphics card. Download the hardware owners manual... http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/poweredge-r710/manuals

Comment: Some discussion here....http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/t/19349460

Comment: If you choose a graphics card that does not need extra power from the PSU it will be easy as plug and play.

Comment: There is no driver for the MG200 gpu and 2012 server, or 2008 server, it is using the default Windows driver, only solution is to upgrade the video adapter using one of the pci slots.